After the first time, How to skip over a expensive calculation and just operate on the result with each subsequent wheelscroll?
I have a function that I need to use on a number of scroll wheel hotkeys, the function increases or decreases a value on controls found on a inactive window, the following is a use case example:
a & WheelUp::                                   ;increment control #1
    lazy_rulers("++", 1, "a")
    return
a & WheelDown::                             ;decrement control #1
    lazy_rulers("--", 1, "a")
    return

b & WheelUp::                                   ;increment control #2
    lazy_rulers("++", 2, "b")
    return
b & WheelDown::                             ;decrement control #2
    lazy_rulers("--", 2, "b")
    return

c & WheelUp::                                   ;increment control #3
    lazy_rulers("++", 3, "c")
    return
c & WheelDown::                             ;decrement control #3
    lazy_rulers("--", 3, "c")
    return

z & WheelUp::                                   ;increment control #26
    lazy_rulers("++", 26, "z")
    return
z & WheelDown::                             ;decrement control #26
    lazy_rulers("--", 26, "z")
    return

Each time I need to increase/decrease this value, I need to perform two steps:

Because the window is QT5 based and the control positions are not constant, I first I have to find a controls relative coordinates using Descolada's UIA
Then using controlClick send wheelUp/wheelDown to the windows coordinates

This works reliably but its very slow. I have looked at it closely, step 2 (controlClick) works fast, its step 1 that is slow, which consists of multiple query's to UIA.
Since I only need to know the controls position once, which is upon the first <letter> + <wheel> event, then while the parent key (letter) is down, I want to skip the UIA step, but I am not sure how to go about this, I tried a number of approaches (keywait, while with getKeystate) but failed.
What is making it difficult is the fact that the code is wrapped in a function, which I need to do so to make use of it in a lot of places, the following is pseudo code:
lazy_rulers(value := "", index := "", key := ""){
if (???){        ; Only enter this branch on the very first wheel scroll (when the letter is first held down, along with the first wheel scroll)
    UIA := UIA_Interface()
    hwnd    := WinExist("Lazy Nezumi Pro ahk_exe LazyNezumiPro.exe")
    el      := UIA.ElementFromHandle(hwnd)
    pos := el.findFirstBy("ControlType=spinner AND AutomationId=LazyNezumi.centralWidget.widgetDetails.animWidgetRulers.frameRulers." rulerParam).GetCurrentPos("window")
    }
;Run the follwoing on every wheel scroll
if (value = "++")
    ControlClick,,% pos.x + 10,% pos.y + 10, wu,,, Lazy Nezumi Pro ahk_exe LazyNezumiPro.exe
else 
    ControlClick,,% pos.x + 10,% pos.y + 10, wd,,, Lazy Nezumi Pro ahk_exe LazyNezumiPro.exe

The function is a lot more involved than the above, but I feel the above gets my point across, I would appreciate any ideas or solutions on this.
